# Can't install Pop!_OS because secure boot won't disable

Tags: system-installation, pop-os, secure-boot

I'm trying to install Pop!_OS on my Windows 10 Acer Aspire E5-573G from a USB stick but I keep getting this message:

```
error: /casper_pop-os_22.04_amd64_nvidia_debug_125/vmlinuz.efi has invalid signature

error: you need to load the kernel first.

Press any key to continue...
```

I already asked how to solve this problem on r/pop_os and they said I need to disable secure boot. So I entered the BIOS, went into the "Boot" tab and tried to disable secure boot but I can't even select "Secure Boot".

Just to be clear, I'd like to install Pop!_OS as my main OS, not as a virtual machine.

[image: Photo of the "Boot" tab of the BIOS]

Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: I did not understand what you mean :)

That is, do you want to install as two boots or do you want to boot in a virtual machine?

Comment: You could check whether there is a supervisor password set for your BIOS. If there is, you won't be able to change your secure boot setting without entering the password first. You can check this on your 'Security' tab (visible in your screenshot).